# C++ judgment conditional formatting question

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int foo(int x,int n);
int main() {
    string s = "hello";
    int k = 0;
    if((k - s.size()) < 0) {
        cout << "yes1";
    }
    int temp = k - s.size();
    if((temp) < 0) {
        cout << "yes2";
    }
}
```

Anyone can tell me why the output is yes2?
Where is the yes1????

Comment: s.size() returns an unsigned integer. `k - s.size()` probably leads to an unsigned integer result which for negative numbers is greater than 0, thus the comparison fails and you don't get "yes1" as output.

Comment: Just say `if (k > s.size())` - and you don't even have to think about signed vs. unsigned.

Comment: To be clear s.size() returns a std::size_t which is a large unsigned integer type.  Another "fix" could be to use k - static_cast<int>(s.size()).  But the general idea is don't mix signed and unsigned types in calculations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `if((k-s.size())<0)`, there was no type casting datatype.

When you write `int temp = k-s.size();`, integer datatype convert result as integer value(-5). Then your result "yes2".

Change `k-s.size()` to `int(k-s.size())`, you will get "yes1" and also "yes2".